# Add days to Date, and store new Date in String

Tags: string, abap

```
DATA: l_str TYPE string,
    l_dat TYPE d.

l_dat = sy-datum.
l_str = l_dat.
WRITE:/ l_str.

l_dat = ( sy-datum + 1 ).
l_str = l_dat.
WRITE:/ l_str.
l_dat = sy-datum.

l_dat = ( l_dat + 1 ).
l_str = l_dat.
WRITE:/ l_str.

l_dat = sy-datum.
l_str = ( l_dat + 1 ).
WRITE:/ l_str.
```

Result in the output (specifically the last line):

```
  20130222
  20130223
  20130223
  734909
```

And what is the best way to do this instead so as always to get the expected values?

Comment: This looks wrong and does not seem to match the official online documentation. If I had this problem, I'd probably issue a SAPnet message and ask SAP to either fix or explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

One way to reliably add/subtract dates is to use a function module, e.g. RP_CALC_DATE_IN_INTERVAL

There is a code example in the SAP Wiki here:
http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/add+or+subtract+dates,+months,years+to+date

Otherwise, you should always do your modifications to the date type field then copy the data into a string field once you have completed your calculations if required.

I have to agree that the behaviour you show does not appear logical, I have duplicated it in our system and get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that assignment to the left hand (string) causes the result of the addition to be converted to an integer before the assignment takes place.

*EDIT* Sorry, I realized you were doing that in your other tests, so I removed my example, just leaving the explanation.

Consider the following from the ABAP keyword doc from *Accessing Character-Like Date Fields and Time Fields Numerically*:

> Numeric access to character-like date fields and time fields exploits
>   the fact that the conversion of the types d and t to numeric values
>   produces an integer number of days or seconds. This applies
>   particularly when using character-like date fields and time fields in
>   numeric calculations, where these fields are converted to the
>   corresponding calculation type.

Because the system does implicit type conversions, it is imaginable that because the addition involves an integer, the resulting type is converted to an integer before the assignment.

In your other examples, the assignment is not the result of an addition but an explicit variable.